# Sony Vegas - Repeat a shot on an axis when panning

Tags: vegas-pro

I'm pretty new to video production and I'm doing a few music videos for an underground rapper and he wanted me to recreate an effect seen in [this](http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhS7W8CRRW0xUz5t0S) video, a good example is from around 1:09 to 1:11. As you can see, the shot is basically cut and the cut-out is panned up, but the video 'repeats' on the X axis, showing the top of the shot at the bottom if that makes sense. My approach to this is creating two duplicate tracks, using the cookie cutter effect on one of them and panning the other, but that doesn't produce the 'repetition' seen in the example. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.